# SQL Query converted to LINQ - DISTINCT Child counts

Tags: sql-server, linq

I am going around in circles with trying to convert this simple SQL to LINQ query syntax.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT p.PID, Count(distinct c.templateID) as AssocTempCnt
FROM Parent p
LEFT JOIN Child c on p.PID = c.PID
GROUP BY p.PID
```

Explanation: I have a parent table whose items might have associations in the child table.  I would like to know how many unique TemplatesIDs the Parent PID is associated with, if any.

### Sample Data:

#### PARENT TABLE

PID, Description
1, ABC
2, XYZ

#### CHILD TABLE

TemplateID, PID, REASON
23, 1, ANY
23, 1, AGAIN
24, 1, DIFFERENT

#### RESULTS

PID - 1     AssocTempCnt - 2
PID - 2     AssocTempCnt - 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following does the trick

```
from p in Parent
join c in Child on p.PID equals c.PID
into cGrp
select new {
  p.PID, 
  AssocTempCnt = cGrp.Select(x => x.templateID).Distinct().Count()
};
```

According to LinqPad,
it gets translated to:

```
SELECT [t0].[PID], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [t1].[templateID]
        FROM [Child] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t0].[PID] = [t1].[PID]
        ) AS [t2]
    ) AS [AssocCount]
FROM [Parent] AS [t0]
```

which should be good enough!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the following LINQ will be translated exactly back to your original SQL, but logically it would be:

```
from p in Parent
join c in Child on p.PID equals c.PID into pcg
from pc in pcg.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
           p.PID, 
           count = (pcg == null ? (int?)null :  
                            (int?)pcg.GroupBy(x => x.templateID).Count())
           }
```

Or if there's already a navigation property between the two:

```
db.Parents
  .Select(p => p.Children == null ? null : 
               p.Children.GroupBy(c => c.templateID).Count()
         );
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. I think the following needs to be added: "group pc by p.PID into y" then change the final select to "select new (y.Key, count = (y == null ? 0 : (int?)y.GroupBy(x => x.PID).Count())".  Thoughts ...